# RavenDb HTTP Patching

Tags: ravendb

Trying to patch documents in RavenDb

```
$a = array('Patches' => array('pref_roles' => "1,2,3"),
                 'Key' => "Users/".$user_id,
                 'Method' => 'Patch'                
);
```

{"Patches":{"pref_roles":"1,2,3"},"Key":"Users/4","Method":"Patch"}

```
$input = json_encode($input);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $input,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:8080/databases/om/bulk_docs'
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

The patch is never getting through. Where am I going wrong?

Edit.

Added in the 'script'

```
$a = array('Patch' => array('Script' => 'this.natio = '.$natio.''),
           'Key' => 'Users/'.$user_id,
           'Method' => 'Patch');
```

I'm posting

```
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
```

to this url :

```
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:8080/databases/om/bulk_docs'
```

With these error messages :

```
Array
(
    [Url] => /databases/om/bulk_docs
    [Error] => System.Exception: Error reading RavenJArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject
   at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJArray.Load(JsonReader reader)
   at Raven.Database.Server.Controllers.RavenBaseApiController.<ReadJsonArrayAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Raven.Database.Server.Controllers.DocumentsBatchController.<BulkPost>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
)
```

Played around a little to see if I could find the working solution but that didn't really work out.

Answer (score 0):

Patch command data in this manner requires that you pass the actual operations.
See:
http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/http-api/http-api-single

I suggest you'll go with Scripted patch, using EVAL.

```
$a = array('Patch' => ('Script' => "this.pref_roles = [1,2,3["),
                 'Key' => "Users/".$user_id,
                 'Method' => 'Patch'                
);
```